# Printing a string pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to print a pattern like this accepting a string as input.

```
EAGLE
AGLEE
GLEEA
LEEAG
EEAGL
EAGLE
```

How can i print like this?

Comment: This question shows absolutely zero prior effort.

Comment: So what did you try for your homework assignment? We do not do your work here.

Comment: JavaScript sorry @Teemu

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking for. What do you mean "a pattern like this". It's very hard to understand what you are even asking for. Once you add that information, then we can further help determine if this is even an appropriate question (or just asking us to do your homework for you).

Comment: I tried multiple times i cant comeup with the logic   .sorry for that@epascarello

Comment: Do you want to left-rotate the string until it is back to its original form? Is this your problem?

Comment: @Kiruba Show what you tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable for the index and iterate until you reach the lenght of the string.

Then take a part of the string beginning from the index until end and the end of the string with another splice.

Display value.

Proceed.

```js
var string = 'EAGLE',
    index = 0;

while (index <= string.length) {
    console.log(string.slice(index) + string.slice(0, index));
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a left-rotate the string until it is back to its original form.

```js
var pattern = 'EAGLE'.split('')
var i = pattern.length + 1

while (i-- > 1) {
  var x = pattern.shift()
  pattern.push(x)
  console.log(pattern.join(''))
}
```